# Scaling down old replicasets while deploying requires data migration

Tags: database, deployment, kubernetes, migration, replicaset

What about ReplicaSet_B and ReplicaSet_A update the same db? I hoped the pods in ReplicaSet_A were stopped with taking a snapshot. But there is not any explanation like this in https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/. I think, It is assumed that the containers are running online applications in the pods. What if they are batch applications? I mean the old pods belonging to old replicas will update the dbs in old manner. This will require also a data migration issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `ReplicaSets` (managed by `Deployments`) make two assumptions: 1. your workload is stateless, and 2. all pods are identical clones (other than their IP addresses). Now, [StatefulSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) address some aspects, for example, you can assign pods a certain identity (for example: leader or follower), but really only work for specific workloads. Also, the [Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) abstractions in Kubernetes won't really help you a lot concerning stateful workloads. What you likely are looking at is a custom controller or operator. We're collecting good practices and tooling via [stateful.kubernetes.sh](https://stateful.kubernetes.sh/), maybe there's something there that can be of help?